# Cocoa WebView cross-thread access

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, multithreading, webkit

I have a C++ class running in its own thread that needs to execute some javascript in a WebView that's part of a Cocoa app. I have the C++ app call a method in the Cocoa window's controller and it in turns runs the javascript, passing in the data. It seems to work part of the time, but crash a lot of the time as well (somewhere in WebView's code). I tried using the @synchronized on the webview instance, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `[yourWebView performSelectorOnMainThread:...]` and friends? (Or call a mediating controller class.)